# 301 wildcard redirect by htaccess without being redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm doing a website on drupal 8.2.6 and it has a problem that in a new browser or computer you can't access the content directly like:
it will redirect you from example.com/abc 
to example.com/index.php
so you can only access the content by 
example.com/index.php/abc
so I want to redirect all the visiting URL like example.com/content to example.com/index.php/content but if we do the usual 301 redirect it will make a redirect loop

I figure out some of the code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.
RewriteRule index.php.$ - [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://andrewyg.net/index.php/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

is it right

Comment: How will it make a redirect loop? Please post what you have tried.

Comment: as we use the normal what ever you use like htaccess or cpanel redirect function you will have a redirect problem by redirecting yourself like: example.com/hi to example.com/index.php/hi and keeps going on until your browser stop prograting